# Installing my module globally not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testJs",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "testJs": "index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I do `npm i -g .` in my project level and I expect to be able to run `testJs` globally, but this is what I'm getting? Any idea?

```
C:\Users\myComputer\testJs>npm i -g .

added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\myComputer\testJs>testJs
'testJs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: They key you have in `bin` is `jsTest` and you are calling `testJs`

Comment: sorry my bad; I typed package.json contect wrong here; I just updated; in package.json Im using `testJs` and in CLI I'm using `testJs` as well

Comment: I just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

As [@tushar-shahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10140124/tushar-shahi) said, you try to running `testJs` instead of `jsTest` after the `npm i -g .`

Comment: sorry my bad; I typed package.json contect wrong here; I just updated; in package.json Im using testJs and in CLI I'm using testJs as well. I just edited my post